# different pic and description visible when sharing a post shared with feed dialog from website

Tags: facebook-like, feed

I created a feed dialog on my website for a news page, I can share this news content without any issue to FB, but once in Facebook I want to share it there, I get the picture and description from a like button on my site.

This is the link for sharing from site to FB

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145350652325572&link=http://nwheelsandheels.be?page=news&picture=<?php echo $fbpic; ?>&name=<?php echo $rij_news['titel']; ?>&caption=Bekijk dit nieuwe nieuwsbericht op Nwheelsandheels.be&description=<?php echo $mes; ?>&redirect_uri=http://www.nwheelsandheels.be?page=news"><img src = "http://www.nwheelsandheels.be/img/share_button2.png"></a>
```

[part1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/g7t1.jpg/)

but when sharing it on FB again I get the picture and details from my like button on the home page.

[part 2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/tmtz.jpg/)

For my like button the details are set in meta tags, can this be the issue (it has a different app id)

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id"          content="190271261128958" /> 
    <meta property="og:type"            content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url"             content="http://www.nwheelsandheels.be" /> 
    <meta property="og:title"           content="N. Wheels and heels" /> 
    <meta property="og:image"           content="http://www.nwheelsandheels.be/img/logofb.png" />
```

Any help will be welcome, Thanks Johan